# How to allocate memory using malloc in mplab x ide, XC16 compiler?

Tags: embedded, pic, mplab, xc16

Can anyone give me a sample code for allocating memory using malloc? 
IDE: mplab x ide
Compiler: XC16 compiler
MCU: PIC24F

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).  Ask a question about the problem you are having rather than about whay *you think* the solution is. As a standard library function using `malloc()` is identical across any platform that supports it.  Section 10.3 of the XC16 user manual states with respect to malloc, calloc and ralloc:  *"If you do not use any of these functions,
then you do not need to allocate a heap. By default, a heap is not created."*.  So if you are having a problem that is probably it, and that is what you should have asked.

Answer (score 1):

Using `malloc` etc. is the same as in any `C` implementation. By default, however, the linker in XC16 will not allocate a heap (from which memory for malloc is taken). You will need to tell the linker to allocate a heap in `Project Properties|xc16-lc|General|Heap size`. The size of the heap must be larger than the largest memory allocations you are making, plus some overhead (see XC16 documentation for details).

Keep in mind that a lot of `malloc/ralloc` activity may fragment the heap, and your heap is not large. So, be mindful of this. A good strategy is to use the heap like a LIFO buffer (i.e. always free memory in the reverse order that it was allocated).

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone give me a sample code for allocating memory using malloc?

```
/* 
     * XC16 v1.31
     * PIC24FJ128GB606
     * MPLAB X IDE v3.65
     * Simulator Debugger
    */

#include <xc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

volatile int i=0;
int main ()
{
    volatile int *ptr= malloc(100*sizeof(int));
    if (ptr == NULL)
        printf ("Cannot allocate memory\n");
    else 
    { 
        printf ("Memory Allocated successfully \n");
        for (i=0; i<(100*sizeof(int)); i++)
        {
            *ptr=i;
            printf ("Pointer value=%d \t i=%d\n",*ptr++,i);
        }
    }
    free ((void *)ptr); 
    return 0;
}
```

Also refer section "Standard C Libraries" under XC16 compiler directory, docs, "16-Bit_Language_Tools_Libraries_Manual.pdf".